# Laravel Retrieve Relationship on Pivot of a non directly related value

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I have a many-to-many relationship on **users** and **postings** table having a pivot table set up and in the pivot table, there is another column *position_id* which is linked to the **positions** table.

In the **User** Model, the many-to-many relationship is defined as:

```
public function postings() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Posting', 'posting_user')->withPivot('position_id','contact_type');
    }
```

And in the **Posting** Model, many-to-many the relationship is defined as:

```
public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Auth\User::class, 'posting_user')->withPivot('position_id','contact_type');
    }
```

And my pivot table looks like :

[image]

And I am accessing data like:

```
$postings = Auth::User()->postings()->get();
```

Now I have to display the **Position Name** on my blade for each of these postings. My problem is from pivot I can only access the position_id number.

```
$postings->first()->pivot->position_id
```

But what I want is to do something like :

```
$postings->first()->pivot->position_id->name
```

Right now I have to make an individual query for each of the records to get the position name, which is not a very good solution.
So is there a better way I can use?

Comment: It sounds like you probably want a `through` relation here, rather `hasManyThrough` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function postings() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Posting', 'posting_user')
            ->withPivot('position_id','contact_type')
            ->using(UserPosting::class);
}
```

**UserPosting.php**

```
class UserPosting extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
    public function position()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Position::class);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
$postings->first()->pivot->position->name
```

[See here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)